# IllegalStateException on a List of Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("hello", "hi", "你好");  
List<String> list3 = Arrays.asList("zhangsan", "lisi", "wangwu", "zhaoliu");  

List<Stream<String>> list2Result = list2.stream().map(item -> list3.stream().map(item2 -> item + " " + item2)).collect(Collectors.toList());

list2Result.forEach(item -> item.collect(Collectors.toList()));
list2Result.forEach(item -> item.forEach(System.out::println));
```

I have to convert list2Result to `List<List<String>>`, but I can't used foreach to print it.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
>          at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
>          at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
>          at com.singhand.proxyServer.Main.lambda$15(Main.java:61)
>          at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
>          at com.singhand.proxyServer.Main.main(Main.java:61)

Comment: Why you did not print into the first `forEach()` ?

Comment: this has been asked A LOT of times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot operate the same `Stream` twice.

Try to collect the list in the first `map`.

```
List<List<String>> list2Result = list2.stream()
        .map(item -> list3.stream()
            .map(item2 -> item + " " + item2)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And print the list of lists in the same way

```
list2Result.forEach(item -> item.forEach(System.out::println));
```

---

If you want a flatten list, try to collect the list using before a `flatMap` which flats multiple streams in one.

```
List<String> list2Result = list2.stream()
        .map(item -> list3.stream()
            .flatMap(item2 -> item + " " + item2))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And then you will have the `List` of strings that can be printed.

```
list2Result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: which stream, list2Result or the stream in the list of list2Result ?

Comment: I edited the answer for List<List<String>>

Comment: thank you, I got it

Comment: You're welcome.